# How to combine bars in Hightcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using **Highcharts** and I have chart looks like this one:

Is there a way to combine each bars in the line into one? It shows few bars that overlap.

**Image of chart:**

[image]

I want to combine them, to just show the start and end date of the bar.
I know that I can remove white border by using `borderWidth: 1,`, but it's not works how it should.

**jsfiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/vcatdsg4/2/

Comment: Have you tried ```border-width: 0```?

http://jsfiddle.net/242v5s8s/1/

Comment: @stpoa
Yes, I am using '0'. But I wonder if there is possibility to link all of these bar into one in way that after putting cursor on it whole bar will be lighted up. So in database I have few bars that are overlap on each other, but in the graph I would like to see combined bars which behave as one.
Example:
<1, 12>,<4,14> but I would like to see <1,14>.
Is there possibility to combine them together? Something like FULL JOIN in SQL.

Comment: You could pre-process your data points before adding as data to series in the chart. Method depends on how you get the data in.